# The National Republican Congressional Committee is now asserting Beto is a furry

Tags: discussion

Is that enough to re-open this question https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/43435/is-beto-a-furry ?

Here's the assertion with some type of photographic evidence.

https://twitter.com/NRCC/status/1106218146359316480

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @DenisS's conclusion, but not the arguments made to reach it.

- The claim is about O'Rourke, not about the NRCC. The NRCC doesn't need to appear in the title.
- The notability is fine. A Google Search finds many people making the claim.
- I agree it has been well-debunked before, making another debunking of limited value.
- My major concern: Google defines "furry" as "an enthusiast for animal characters with human characteristics, in particular a person who dresses up in costume as such a character or uses one as an avatar online." That makes it a question about what is going on in O'Rourke's mind, which is a motivation question. [The counter-argument being: we can undermine the crappy evidence given in favour, even if we can't give any reliable evidence either way.]

Comment: I do appreciate the even handedness of the first and fourth bullets though.  It's not about NRCC or anyone else.  The claim is O'Rourke.  Solid logic and good editing.

Answer (score 3):

Even if the question was not deleted, there would still be plenty of issues with the question.

1. The title "Is Beto a Furry?" doesn't fit the clinical tone required for this site.  A better title would be "Is the NRCC correct in asserting that Beto O'Rourke is a Furry?"
2. Calling O'Rourke "failed TX Senate candidate" violates the neutral tone required for this site.  If you're going to describe him, call him either "Former U.S. Representative" or (with developments since the question was posted) "2020 Democratic Presidential Candidate".
3. As previously stated in the comments, the source cited isn't notable.  You would have to change the question to cite the NRCC, not a Twitter personality.
4. Regardless of the previous issues, the claim is VERY easily debunked.  [A cursory google search revealed that this is a screen shot of a video from a band he was a member of in the 90s and early 00s](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/2019/01/heres-video-of-beto-orourke-singing-blitzkrieg-bop-in-a-sheep-mask-and-a-onesie/).  It is not a fursuit, as the NRCC is implicitly claiming, but a onesie.  The mask is worn not because O'Rouke wants to be an animal, but because it's part of the act of the band.

Comment: You do realize that all of this, even O'Rourke's presidential announcement, is all new information, right?  Like yesterday.  And how can you answer so definitively that the reason he donned a furry costume is because he didn't want to be a furry?

Comment: @KDog 1. The "Former U.S. Representative" title is not. Calling him "failed TX Senate candidate" is not a neutral tone.  I've adjusted the answer considering the other title.  2. The reason that the NRCC is saying he's a furry is because he was wearing a jumpsuit and an animal mask.  By that same logic, every person who has ever worn an animal mask/costume is a furry.  O'Rourke has explictly stated that it was an act for a band.  If you want to make a new question, you can try, but you're going to get the same result (downvotes/deletion) if you don't take my advice.

Comment: Why would it matter what  Beto says?  Of course he's going to claim he isn't a furry.  He obviously has severe integrity issues with his criminal past.  And would love to hear why a onesie is not a furry costume.  Seriously, what's the difference?

Comment: @KDog wearing an animal costume != being a furry.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furry_fandom in the section under "Activities".  The only section that this "proof" satisfies is the Roleplaying section.  But again, not all animal costumes are furry costumes.  Otherwise, the millions of people who dress up as animals for Halloween are furries.  Anyone who has dressed up as an animal for a play is a furry.  Hell, by that logic, I'm a furry, because I dressed as the Big Bad Wolf with my ex for Halloween years ago.